# Condition on a complex linear system to have real solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ square matrix with complex entries and $b\in\Bbb C^n$ an arbitrary vector. Are there known sufficient and necessary conditions on $A$ such that the system
$$
Ax=b
$$
admits a **real** solution, i.e. $x\in\Bbb R^n$?

Generally speaking, to be solvable we need $A$ to be invertible, then we need $A^{-1}b\in\Bbb R^n$, but I wonder whether there exists some known condition on $A$.

Answer (score 3):

We can right $A = \bar{A} + i \hat{A}$, and $b = \bar{b} + i \hat{b}$, where $\bar{A}, \hat{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $\bar{b}, \hat{b} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. If $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfies $Ax = b$, then we must have $\bar{A}x = \bar{b}$ and $\hat{A}x = \hat{b}$. If both $\bar{A}$ and $\hat{A}$ are invertible, then the criteria for $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ becomes simple, which is, if $$\bar{A}^{-1}\bar{b} = \hat{A}^{-1}\hat{b}$$

However if they are not invertible the criteria must be much complicated.

**Edit:** Otherwise, for $Ax = b$ to be solvable we must have $\bar{b} \in \mathcal{C}(\bar{A})$, $\hat{b} \in \mathcal{C}(\hat{A})$ and $\{x \mid \bar{A}x = \bar{b}\} \cap \{x \mid \hat{A}x = \hat{b}\} \ne \emptyset$.